# Check git pull changes

Tags: git, pull

My changes are on mainline and committed them and did a pull for latest changes using

`git pull --rebase`

It succeeded. 
Now how can I check what are the new changes added to my branch through pull?

For example let's assume I am working on branch master. I have my local commited changes on file xyz.java and I did a pull adding latest changes on abc.java.

Now how can I see only changes on abc.java not in xyz.java?

I couldn't find answer anywhere. Any answer or document link is appreciated.

Comment: Try `git diff ${branch}@{1}..${branch}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking you haven't commited any new changes afterwards in your git so here is the solution:

1. Run git log --graph --oneline

This will show all the Merges in the order such that latest merges are shown there

2. Now Copy the commit number of that commit just below your merge message or it might probably be 2nd most recent commit

Example for point 2: [see this image of git log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLubM.jpg) here 2nd most recent commit is 354dfdd note it down in your case

3. Now come out of log by pressing q and type **git show 354dfdd**

This will show changes in abc.java and whatever files you have edited in the commit before it before merging

**NOTE:** Commit number 354dfdd is for reference sake, you have to copy your commit number and replace the copied one to point 3

Comment: Though it is not a single step. But I got what I want. Thanks!

Comment: Hope this helps but cannot understand downvoting

Answer (score -1):

> Now how can I check what are the new changes added to my branch through pull?

```
# verify that all the commits and branches are merged in
git log --oneline --decorate --graph
```

---

> Now how can I see only changes on abc.java not in xyz.java?

```
# show all the commits which modified the given file
git log -p <filename>
```

Comment: I got all commit history but not the actual changes that are added to my local branch on doing pull and "Now how can I see only changes on abc.java not in xyz.java?" what I mean is what are changes but not literally a single or specific files.